# ruby on rails "before_save" in parent model to check attribut of child

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model 'place_detail' that has many a child 'emails'

```
has_many :emails, :dependent => :destroy
```

and in the email model:

```
belongs_to :place_detail
```

Now in the place_detail i want to make sur i added a email to check a attribut 'has_email'
so i added:

```
before_save :check_if_has_email
...
def check_if_has_email
  if emails.count >0
    self.has_email = true;
  else
    self.has_email = false;
  end
end
```

the **problem** is that the attribute has_email does not check event if i created a email child. what i understand is that the parent is saved **before** the child

how can i get my has_email checked in place_detail when i create a child email?

---

EDIT:
 I could simply put the has_email boolean in a method like

```
def has_email?
  if self.emails.count >0
     return true
..
```

but i prefer the boolean in the attribute because i use it in many scope and it would be a lot a change in the app

Comment: Why do you want to persist `has_email` when you can do `place_detail.emails.count` at any time? We'll need some more context.

Comment: i know there could be other solution and i could acheive a equivalent result be making change in my application. But i prefer this solution and i also want to know what to do when you need the information of a new child child before saving the parent

Answer (score 1):

This will ensure that your model has at least one email (place it in your model file `place_detail.rb`)

```
has_many :emails, :dependent => :destroy
validates :emails, :length => { :minimum => 1 }
```

EDIT:

One suggestion would be just to check the trait `place_detail.emails` count when you need it.  If you examine such data multiple times a request you can store it like so

```
def has_email?
   (result ||= self.emails.count) > 0
end
```

That way it will only check your database once

Comment: good idea but i really just want to update the has_email ' not prevent the place_detail from being saved

Comment: Oh so, `has_email` is an attribute in `place_detail`?  I see.  My suggestion would be to simply check if place_detail has an email `place_detail.email.count > 0` when and if you use that information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're forced to use the 'has_email' attribute within the place_detail model, you could simply save the place_detail in the Create method of the Email controller.

```
@email = Email.new(email_params)
@email.place_detail.save
```